# Don't understand concatenation operator (++)

Tags: haskell

I have a question about list concatenation. The function plus plus (++) work is different with parentheses

```
(++ "abc") ("xyz") >>> it's xyzabc
(++) "abc" "xyz"   >>> it's abcxyz
```

---

I think it's because:

```
(++ "abc") ("xyz") >>> "xyz" ++ "abc"
(++) "abc" "xyz"   >>> "abc" ++ "xyz"
```

But why, and have any document talk about that?

I continue to test with "subtract" function. The result as my expect:

```
(subtract 10) (5) >>> -5
(subtract) 10 5   >>> -5
```

Comment: `(op x) => \a -> a op x`; `(x op) => \a -> x op a`; `(op) x y => \x y -> x op y`

Comment: @freestyle maybe, I think so, but you have any document talk about function (++) implement like that?

Comment: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-280003.4

Comment: The function is called `(++)`. `(++ "abc")` is *not* a normal function call - see how it doesn't even contain the name of the function! `((++) "abc")` would do what you expect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `++` is an operator, Haskell expects it to be in an infix position. Adding parens on either side will tell Haskell to treat it as a prefix function. That's why

```
(++) "abc" "xyz"      -- "abc" ++ "xyz"
```

works the way it does. However, having a paren on just one side of an operator, like `(++ "abc")` or `("abc" ++)` is something special called a [section](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator) - it essentially produces a function that would "fill in" the missing argument

```
(++ "abc")        -- equivalent to `\x -> x ++ "abc"`
("abc" ++)        -- equivalent to `\x -> "abc" ++ x`
```

Then, `(++ "abc") ("xyz")` is equivalent to `(\x -> x ++ "abc") ("xyz")` is equivalent to `"xyz" ++ "abc"`.

Comment: +1, beat me to finding the "section" concept. I think it would be nice to add a little about the `subtract` function that the OP mentions; how the same logic doesn't apply because `subtract` is a function and not an operator. (Showing the difference between `(-) 10 5` and `(subtract) 10 5`).

Comment: The last one looks wrong `(- 2) 1` is a type error, since that's unary minus. Also, `subtract 2 1` yields -1. Indeed, `(-e)` is a special-case since it is not a section, precisely because unary minus exists which conflicts :-( `subtract` exists to be able to express these missing sections.

Comment: @chi Ack. I keep getting bitten by this. I don't even use unary minus in my code, I'm perfectly happy with `negate`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the second one. This is a case of **prefix notation**. Here, and if you are aware of the [prefix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) of using operators, you would see the result "abcxyz" to be more intuitive. Basically, in this representation of operational expressions, the operator comes first, followed by the sequence of operands, which in this case is two. So, it treats "abc" as the first operand and "xyz" as the second operand and does the concatenation in the standard expected manner, i.e. the second/right operand is added to the right of the first/left operand.

Whereas, the first one is a case of **currying**. Basically, concatenation (++), being a multi-argument function can be equally expressed as a series of one argument functions, where by supplying one argument at a time, we are transforming our original function requiring `n` arguments (better read "expression" as denoted in Haskell) into another function which takes `n-1` arguments. So, here the original 2-argument function (++) gets converted to a 1-argument function (++ "abc"). Now, it can be read as a function which appends "abc" to any string provided as an input, which is confirmed by our output as well.

Comment: It's important to note that operator sections are one step beyond currying. `(++ "abc")` and `("abc" ++)` are both legal, as is `((++) "abc")`, but `("abc" (++))` is not. Since binary operators are, well, binary, you can specify the single argument in either position, not just the first one as with ordinary multi-argument functions.